# How to allow asynchronous results to wait for other asynchronous results to finish in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, socket.io

Say I have the code.

```
function A(){
  return "something";
}

function B (){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
  setTimeout(function(){return "something else"}, randomNumber);
}

function C (){
  setTimeout(function(){return "this was called from the server"}, 2000);
}

var socket = io();
socket.on('special event', function(){
    C();
});

B();
A();
```

Now I want each function to finish completely before the next function happens.  With function A and B I can use a callback easily enough.  But with a random event in socket.io I'm not quite sure how I can reference function B (if it hasn't finished) from function C or from inside the callback in socket.on.  I know jQuery includes a promise Object but I'm not quite sure how I would utilize that in this situation.

Comment: Look into EventEmitter for Node.JS. Did something similar using that library.

Comment: But that would make them synchronous with one another, or am I reading it wrong.

Comment: So you want to listen to the _random event_ only after `A` and `B` are finished, so every event that occurs before should be ignored?

Comment: @Dellirium they can't be synchronous because socket.on happens asynchronously.

Comment: @t.niese I want each event to finish before the next one is allowed to begin.  So B starts, the timeout occurs, it returns something.  Only then is A allowed to start.  If C is called but B is waiting for the timeout to finish, I want B to finish the timeout, return something and then C is allowed to begin execution.

Comment: But the `speical event` is allowed to be received before `A` or `B` is finished?

Comment: @Vic is this what you're referring to? https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous

Comment: @t.niese no, the moment 'special event' happens C is called, however if at that time B has been called and the timeout is still happening I don't want C to be executed until B is finished.  Unless there's a way to make the socket.on listener to wait for any other async calls to finish.

Comment: I'm so confused. Is there a specific order of execution for the functions a, b, c? Or do you want them to "wait for their turn" if one of them is running?

Comment: My question is how it should behave. My understanding was: `A` should execute first, then when `A` is finished, `B` will be executed. When `B` finished, then `C` will be executed, but only after `special event`  was received by the server. But my question is, does it matter when you receive `special event` do you want to take a `special event` into account that is received before `B` finished, or only `special event` that are received after `B` was finished?

Comment: @Vic yeah all I want is for them to wait their turn.  if C is called and B is still waiting for setTimeout to complete I want B to finish, then C can start.

Comment: From my understanding you want a complete synchronous calling of these functions, if each one waits for the other one to finish its just not async at all. Make a queue, and call "next" once whichever is being processed is done

Answer (score 0):

A Promise based version could look that way. You will create one Promise `specialEventWaiter` that will be resolve as soon as the socket receives `special event`, and this Promise will be used as halting point between the execution of `B` and `C` in the Promise chain.

```
var socket = io();

// create a promise that will be resolved as soon as 'special event' is received
var specialEventWaiter = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  socket.once('special event', function() {
    resolve()
  });
})


function A() {
  return Promise.resolve("something")
}

function B() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("something else")
    }, randomNumber);
  })
}

function C() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("this was called from the server")
    }, 2000);
  })
}


A()
  .then(() => B())
  .then(specialEventWaiter) // here we wait until the event was received (this could already happen before A or B are finished.
  .then(() => C())
  .then(() => {
    console.log('finished')
  })
```